# How to get rid of (or make even) vertical space above and below math mode (`\[...\]` and `\begin{equation}`)?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath, vertical, vspace

I have difficulty removing spaces (or making them even, or setting them to custom values) above and below vertical math mode.

This is a re-write of the previous question whose code contained `hrule`'s and environments with display-mode (instead of vertical-mode) math, which (I've been informed) made it difficult (or impossible, judging by absence of solutions) to get rid of vertical spacing. As you can see, the problem (of properly removing vertical spacing) persists.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  line 1 y
  \begin{equation*}\sqrt[3]{4}\end{equation*}
  line 2 y
  \[\sqrt[3]{4}\]
  line 3 y
\end{document}
```

[image]

When set to 0pt, `abovedisplayskip`, `abovedisplayshortskip`, `belowdisplayskip`, and `belowdisplayshortskip` do not remove bottom space (they just shorten it).

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
 \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
 \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
 \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}
  line 1 y
  \begin{equation*}\sqrt[3]{4}\end{equation*}
  line 2 y
  \[\sqrt[3]{4}\]
  line 3 y
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Further experiments indicates that the `\hrule`s are turning off the `\abovedisplayskip`.  What is left is the amount of space reserved for equation itself, which can be mostly filled using `\rule[-8pt]{1pt}{22pt}`.

Comment: Why don't you just set the skips to zero?

Comment: as I said on your last question you should never add these negative spaces they break all latex's spacing logic, just set the spacing around display constructs to the values that you want. You should never have a display math environment at the start of a paragraph (eg after the `\hrule`) otherwise you do not get vertical space but a spurious blank line of paragraph with no text.

Comment: you can use `\showoutput` to see the exact spaces used.

Comment: @bp2017 - Trial and error.  The 1pt is just the width.

Comment: the spacing before a math expression is `\abovedisplayskip` or `\abovedisplayshortskip` simply set those to what you need, why do you need to insert negative space?

Comment: @bp2017 if you show an example it can be debugged but as i say never start a display equation in vertical mode or you will get a spurious blank line (an empty line of a paragraph not vertical space) but in general adding `\showoutput`  will show the space you are getting

Comment: yes but it is an error to follow `\hrule` (which is a vertical mode TeX primitive not a latex command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I use `article` and `\vbox` to allow for `\showoutput`, the result from

```latex
\documentclass{article}%[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\vbox{\hsize=4em \parindent=0pt
 \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
 \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
 \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
 \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}
  line 1 y
  \begin{equation*}\sqrt[3]{4}\end{equation*}
  line 2 y
  \[\sqrt[3]{4}\]
  line 3 y
}
\showoutput
\end{document}
```

is

```latex
...\vbox(54.94444+1.94444)x40.00006
....\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x40.00006, glue set 7.5fil
.....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 1
.....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 y
.....\penalty 10000
.....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\abovedisplayskip) 0.0
....\glue(\baselineskip) 0.4952
....\hbox(9.56036+0.8396)x13.9585, shifted 13.02078, display
.....\hbox(9.56036+0.8396)x13.9585
......\kern 0.0
......\kern 2.77771
......\hbox(3.22221+0.0)x3.40283, shifted -5.2325
.......\mathon
.......\OT1/cmr/m/n/5 3
.......\mathoff
......\kern -5.55542
......\kern 0.0
......\hbox(9.56036+0.8396)x13.33337
.......\mathon
.......\hbox(9.56036+0.8396)x13.33337
........\hbox(0.39998+9.6)x8.33336, shifted -8.7604
.........\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 p
........\vbox(9.56036+0.0)x5.00002
.........\kern0.39998
.........\rule(0.39998+0.0)x*
.........\kern2.31596
.........\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x5.00002
..........\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 4
.......\mathoff
....\penalty 0
....\glue(\belowdisplayskip) 0.0
....\glue(\baselineskip) 4.21596
....\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x40.00006, glue set 7.5fil
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 2
.....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 y
.....\penalty 10000
.....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\abovedisplayskip) 0.0
....\glue(\baselineskip) 0.4952
....\hbox(9.56036+0.8396)x13.9585, shifted 13.02078, display
.....\hbox(9.56036+0.8396)x13.9585
......\kern 0.0
......\kern 2.77771
......\hbox(3.22221+0.0)x3.40283, shifted -5.2325
.......\mathon
.......\OT1/cmr/m/n/5 3
.......\mathoff
......\kern -5.55542
......\kern 0.0
......\hbox(9.56036+0.8396)x13.33337
.......\mathon
.......\hbox(9.56036+0.8396)x13.33337
........\hbox(0.39998+9.6)x8.33336, shifted -8.7604
.........\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10 p
........\vbox(9.56036+0.0)x5.00002
.........\kern0.39998
.........\rule(0.39998+0.0)x*
.........\kern2.31596
.........\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x5.00002
..........\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 4
.......\mathoff
....\penalty 0
....\glue(\belowdisplayskip) 0.0
....\glue(\baselineskip) 4.21596
....\hbox(6.94444+1.94444)x40.00006, glue set 7.5fil
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 l
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 i
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 n
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
.....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 3
.....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
.....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 y
.....\penalty 10000
.....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

which shows where the space you see comes from: from `\baselineskip`.

Try with

```latex
\documentclass{article}%[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\noindent\vbox{\hsize=4em \parindent=0pt
 \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
 \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
 \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
 \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}
  line 1 y
  \begin{equation*}\sqrt[3]{4}\end{equation*}
  line 2 y
  \[\sqrt[3]{4}\]
  line 3 y
}\vrule
\vbox{\hsize=4em \parindent=0pt
 \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
 \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
 \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
 \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}
  line 1 y\par
  4\par
  line 2 y\par
  4\par
  line 3 y
}

\end{document}
```

and you'll get

[image]

It's not at all clear *what* space you want to remove.

Comment: @bp2017 That's it: visual perception. With standard above and below skips, the problem vanishes. With short lines like those it seems a problem, but it really isn't.

Comment: Problem vanishes when skips are zeroed (to 0pt). When they remain untouched (standard), I have no idea how they compare to regular text lines (juxtaposed).

Answer (score 1):

it is normally an error to start a paragraph with a displayed equation as otherwise, as you show here, you get a spurious blank first line of a paragraph, you can supress that with `\noindent` if it can not be avoided,

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}
\setlength\jot{0pt}
\Huge
  hello world
  \hrule height 0.01pt
\noindent
    \begin{gather*}\boxed{2+2=4}\end{gather*}
    %\[\begin{gathered}\boxed{2+2=4}\end{gathered}\]
  \hrule height 0.01pt
  hello world
\end{document}
```

Note that the difficulty here of adjusting the white space and the need for `\noindent` is due to the `\hrule` which adversly affects the spacing as it forces the end of the paragraph before the display. If the `\[` had immediately followed the `Hello World` text as would be more normal, then the `\noindent` would not be required.

Comment: it really makes no sense, why don't you use `hrule\hbox{$1+2=3$}\hrule` if you want no spacing, why use a display environment like `gather` designed to set of teh math with reasonable spacing and then to disable all its features?

Comment: @bp2017 the `\hrule `are not "keeping track of spacing!!!!`  they are the main source of the spacing problems you are having they completely change the spacing of the display math.

Comment: @bp2017 I don't know how often i can say that you should never start a paragraph with display math or you get the spurious spacing that you show. `\hrule` ends the paragraph after `hello world` and so forces incorrect spacing of the display. It also hides the depth of any characters in teh preceding line so spoils the normal baseline adjustment.

Comment: extra space added around math multi-line display lines it defaults to 3pt, you get an overlap in the example if you don't account for it